# Script to make all (or specified names of) public boards private

Tags: pinterest

I don't like the way Pinterest does not allow one to move a public board to a secret board. They say it's because the comments from public users cannot be moved to the secret board (which will allow only certain authorized users to see its contents).

So, I would like a script to make all (or specified names of) public boards private by just downloading all full images and associated text and re-uploading them to Pinterest.

Where can I find such software?